# Rectangular area light specular factor following Epic's SIGGRAPH 2013 notes

Tags: opengl, deferred-rendering

I'm trying to implement area lights following Epic's notes from SIGGRAPH 2013. They provide a method for a tube area light which I have already implemented and it's working. Now I'm trying to implement rectangular area lights as well, following a similar approach to the one used to the tube light.

Thinking that the tube light is just a rectangular light Always facing the shaded point with two semi-spheres on the edges, I modified the calculation of the most representative point given by Epic.

This is how the input data for the MRP calculation is computed:

```
vec3 R  = reflect(-viewDirection, normal);

vec3 P0 = LightPosition + LightLeft * -halfWidth;
vec3 P1 = LightPosition + LightLeft *  halfWidth;
vec3 L0 = P0 - worldPosition;
vec3 L1 = P1 - worldPosition;

vec3 LightVector = GetRectangularLightLForSpecular(L0, L1, R, halfHeight, LightUp);
```

This is my modified function to compute the MRP:

```
vec3 GetRectangularLightLForSpecular(vec3 L0, vec3 L1, vec3 R, float halfHeight, vec3 up)
{
    float distL0 = length(L0);
    float distL1 = length(L1);

    vec3 Ld = L1 - L0;
    float RdotL0 = dot(R, L0);
    float RdotLd = dot(R, Ld);
    float L0dotLd = dot(L0, Ld);
    float distLd = length(Ld);
    float t = (RdotL0 * RdotLd - L0dotLd) / (distLd * distLd - RdotLd * RdotLd);

    vec3 closestPoint = L0 + Ld * clamp(t, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    vec3 centerToRay = dot(closestPoint, R) * R - closestPoint;

    // This is where I made the change
    // This is the original line of code from Epic's notes: 
    // closestPoint = closestPoint + centerToRay * clamp(radius / length(centerToRay), 0.0f, 1.0f);
    // The following line is my version:
    closestPoint = closestPoint + centerToRay * halfHeight;

    return normalize(closestPoint);
}
```

As you can see from this picture, the result is not really right since the shape of the reflected light on the plane surgafe has "caps" on each end.

[image]